# How to expose a list of lists from C++ to Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

**I want to expose a list of QStringlist from C++ to Qml and access its elements and their methods from the QML side.**

*Here What I've done so far:*

this my .h file for a class called manager.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QList>

class Manager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList imagesPaths READ imagesPaths)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList imagesPaths READ imagesPaths2)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QStringList> imagesPathsLists READ imagesPathsLists)

public:
    explicit Manager(QObject *parent = 0);

    QStringList imagesPaths() const;
    QStringList imagesPaths2() const;
    QList<QStringList> imagesPathsLists()const;

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QStringList m_imagesPaths;
    QStringList m_imagesPaths2;
    QList<QStringList> m_imagesPathsLists;

};
```

This is my .CPP file for the class methods implementations

```
#include "manager.h"

Manager::Manager(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_imagesPaths << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four";
    m_imagesPaths2 << "one-2" << "two-2" << "three-2" << "four-2";
    m_imagesPathsLists << m_imagesPaths << m_imagesPaths2;
}

QStringList Manager::imagesPaths() const
{
    return m_imagesPaths;
}

QStringList Manager::imagesPaths2() const
{
    return m_imagesPaths2;
}

QList<QStringList> Manager::imagesPathsLists() const
{
    return m_imagesPathsLists;
}
```

And the main.cpp file which contain the registration for my Class

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include "manager.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;

    Manager *mng = new Manager();
    QQmlContext *ctxt = viewer.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("Manager",mng);

    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/listOfLists/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Finally the .Qml file which is trying to get data from the lists

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            for(var i = 0; i < Manager.imagesPathsLists.count(); i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < Manager.imagesPathsLists[i].count(); j++){
                    console.log(Manager.imagesPathsLists[i].at(j))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click on the rectangle I get the following error

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QList<QStringList>' for property 'Manager::imagesPathsLists'
file:///E:/DevWork/build-listOfLists-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/qml/listOfLists/main.qml:10: TypeError: Cannot call method 'count' of undefined
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for two days now. I tried **QQmlListProperty** but with no success I don't know What I mess.

Comment: @KubaOber Well the thread you mentioned doesn't address my problem, I already succeeded in exposing QstringList to the Qml, but the issue here is I'm trying to expose a QList<QStringlist> the same way I did with the QStringList but it is not working.
And I receive this error 
`QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QList<QStringList>' for property 'Manager::imagesPathsLists'`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that detail.

Comment: Did you tried to register your data type with QMetaData ?

Comment: @CapelliC I'm using QStringList should I register it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you are trying to do by simply putting the `QList<QStringList>` in a container class which derives from QObject. The following example will explain it.

listoflist.h

```
#ifndef LISTOFLIST_H
#define LISTOFLIST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
class ListOfList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ListOfList(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setListOfList(const QList<QStringList>& listOfList);
    Q_INVOKABLE qint32 count() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE qint32 subCount(const int & index) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QString at(const int &i,const int &j);
signals:

public slots:

private:
    QList<QStringList> m_listOfList;
};

#endif // LISTOFLIST_H
```

listoflist.cpp

```
#include "listoflist.h"

ListOfList::ListOfList(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void ListOfList::setListOfList(const QList<QStringList> &listOfList)
{
    m_listOfList = listOfList;
}

qint32 ListOfList::count() const
{
    return m_listOfList.count();
}

qint32 ListOfList::subCount(const int &index) const
{
    int subCount = -1;
    if(index>=0 && index<m_listOfList.count())
    {
        subCount = m_listOfList.at(index).count();
    }
    return subCount;
}

QString ListOfList::at(const int &i, const int &j)
{
    QString value;
    if(i>=0 && i<m_listOfList.count())
    {
        if(j>=0 && j<m_listOfList.at(i).count())
        {
            value = m_listOfList.at(i).at(j);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

manager.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QList>
#include <listoflist.h>
class Manager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList imagesPaths READ imagesPaths)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList imagesPaths READ imagesPaths2)
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject* imagesPathsLists READ imagesPathsLists)

public:
    explicit Manager(QObject *parent = 0);

    QStringList imagesPaths() const;
    QStringList imagesPaths2() const;
    QObject* imagesPathsLists();

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QStringList m_imagesPaths;
    QStringList m_imagesPaths2;
    QList<QStringList> m_imagesPathsLists;
    ListOfList m_listOfList;

};
```

manager.cpp

```
#include "manager.h"

Manager::Manager(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_imagesPaths << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four";
    m_imagesPaths2 << "one-2" << "two-2" << "three-2" << "four-2";
    m_imagesPathsLists << m_imagesPaths << m_imagesPaths2;
    m_listOfList.setListOfList(m_imagesPathsLists);
}

QStringList Manager::imagesPaths() const
{
    return m_imagesPaths;
}

QStringList Manager::imagesPaths2() const
{
    return m_imagesPaths2;
}

QObject *Manager::imagesPathsLists()
{
    return &m_listOfList;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include "manager.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;

    Manager *mng = new Manager();
    QQmlContext *ctxt = viewer.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("Manager",mng);

    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/SO_ListOfLists/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

       return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var count = Manager.imagesPathsLists.count();
            for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                var subCount = Manager.imagesPathsLists.subCount(i);
                console.debug("StringList number ->" + (i+1))
                for(var j=0;j<subCount;j++)
                {
                    var string = Manager.imagesPathsLists.at(i,j)
                    console.debug(string)
                }
                console.debug("---------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's quite a bit of boilerplate for such simple functionality.

Comment: Using invokables (for count etc.) has the issue that you can't use them in bindings properly, i.e. the binding won't update when e.g. the count changes. Use properties instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [QVariantList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object) instead of QList for imagesPathsLists property.

*The QML engine provides automatic type conversion between QVariantList and JavaScript arrays, and between QVariantMap and JavaScript objects.*

.h :

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QList>

class Manager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList imagesPathsLists READ imagesPathsLists)

public:
    explicit Manager(QObject *parent = 0);

    QVariantList imagesPathsLists() const;

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QVariantList m_imagesPathsLists;
};
```

.cpp :

```
#include "manager.h"

Manager::Manager(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QStringList inner1;
    inner1 << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four";
    QStringList inner2;
    inner2 << "one-2" << "two-2" << "three-2" << "four-2";
    m_imagesPathsLists << QVariant(inner1) << QVariant(inner2);
}
```

.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            for(var i = 0; i < Manager.imagesPathsLists.length(); i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < Manager.imagesPathsLists[i].length(); j++){
                    console.log(Manager.imagesPathsLists[i][j])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, QML does not translate list types other than those enumerated in the documentation. So, while `QStringList` works, `QList<QStringList>` doesn't.

You can use `QVariantList` and populate it with variants that carry a `QStringList`. That should work.

Comment: It seems that, I  cannot access custom class once it has been passed to QML as `QVariant`

Comment: @AllanRuin That's an entirely different question, then - please ask it, with sufficient detail. This question was very specific and there was nothing in it about any custom types.